# Can't seem to find the correct CSS selectors for public buttons - contributions pages (Save, Cancel and Review Your Contribution)

Tags: wordpress, css

Does anyone have the correct CSS Selectors for these 3 buttons? I want to remove the icons (they don't display on all browsers) and change the overall style of the buttons to match buttons on the rest of the site.

https://wordpress-435088-1363156.cloudwaysapps.com/join/
https://wordpress-435088-1363156.cloudwaysapps.com/volunteer-scpa/

Comment: Hi Larry, I can see that you're missing some styling on your icons. I'm not sure if it's related (but likely): you have a lot of javascript errors on the join page - it looks like the CiviCRM javascript (which is essential to the proper functioning) is not being loaded for those pages.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
div.crm-submit-buttons i { display: none; }
div.crm-submit-buttons span { /* your styling */ }
div.crm-submit-buttons input { /* your styling */ }
```

If you want it specific to the page you'd add something like `div.crm-contribution-page-id-1` or `div.crm-profile-name-volunteer_interest` in front.

Comment: thank you for you help!